# Getting phone number from Facebook AccountKit when using AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE

Tags: android, facebook

The Facebook AccountKit documentation states that if your began the login session with `AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN`, it's possible to access the Account Kit ID, phone number and email of the current account via a call to `getCurrentAccount()`.

Is it possible to access the phone number using the method `getCurrentAccount()` if you begin the login session using `AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ResponseType as CODE the access token and phone number will not be passed back to the client SDK. You'll be able to get the phone number on your server.

See an illustration here: https://fb-s-d-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-xpa1/t39.2365-6/12057091_480836178775274_72687398_n.jpeg

See instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/graphapi